# getUserMedia on click only

Tags: getusermedia

I'm trying to capture video/photo from webcam. I've foun a script working, but I would like to start the camera access only on button click. With this script it will start immediatly (I don't want to). How can I bind this event on click please?

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
                context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
                video = document.getElementById("video"),
                videoObj = { "video": true },
                errBack = function(error) {
                    console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code);
                };

            // Put video listeners into place
            if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
                navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
                    video.src = stream;
                    video.play();
                }, errBack);
            } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
                navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                    video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                    video.play();
                }, errBack);
            }

            // Trigger photo take
            document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 487, 365);
            });
        }, false);
```

Comment: You got some good help -- should probably mark an answer, to give helper points.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call getUserMedia in a click handler instead of during the DOM content loaded event.

I took the code in your question, and modified it:

- Made it part of a whole html document so I could test it
- Wrapped the code that starts the camera in a function, called startCamera
- Added a "start camera" button.  You could start the camera with the snap button is clicked, but that didn't really make sense to me.
- Added a click listener to the "start camera" button, which simply executes the startCamera function

Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <video id="video"></video>
        <button id="startCamera">Start camera</button>
        <button id="snap">Take snapshot</button>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
                context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
                video = document.getElementById("video"),
                videoObj = { "video": true },
                errBack = function(error) {
                    console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code);
                };

            // Put video listeners into place
            function startCamera() {
                if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
                    navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
                        video.src = stream;
                        video.play();
                    }, errBack);
                } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
                    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                        video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                        video.play();
                    }, errBack);
                }
            }

            // Trigger photo take
            document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 487, 365);
            });
            // Trigger starting the camera
            document.getElementById("startCamera").addEventListener("click", function() {
                startCamera();
            });
        }, false);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This code. Also try to run this from a virtual directory.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doGetUserMedia() {
            // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canv"),
                context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
                video = document.getElementById("video"),
                videoObj = { "video": true },
                errBack = function(error) {
                    console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code);
                };

            // Put video listeners into place
            if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
                navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
                    video.src = stream;
                    video.play();
                }, errBack);
            } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
                navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                    video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                    video.play();
                }, errBack);
            }

            // Trigger photo take
            document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 487, 365);
            });
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="doGetUserMedia()">Start Camera</button>
<video id="video" width="487" height="365"></video>
<button id="snap">Take snapshot</button>
<canvas id="canv" width="487" height="365"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doGetUserMedia() {
            // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
                context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
                video = document.getElementById("video"),
                videoObj = { "video": true },
                errBack = function(error) {
                    console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code);
                };

            // Put video listeners into place
            if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
                navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
                    video.src = stream;
                    video.play();
                }, errBack);
            } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
                navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
                    video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                    video.play();
                }, errBack);
            }

            // Trigger photo take
            document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 487, 365);
            });
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="doGetUserMedia()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```